# Samba share not appearing on smart TV

Tags: linux, samba, gentoo

I reinstalled my Gentoo installation and after that I tried to get the Samba server to show on a smart TV, as it did before I reinstalled, but even though I had the old configuration file, it didn't show up in the menu. This is the configuration for the share:

```
[MyShare]
   comment = Shared Directory
   path = /share
   browsable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   guest account = guest
```

I have not made any changes to the default config except this. I have a guest account and it has a password set by `smbpasswd`. Everything should work, but it doesn't. Do I have to make additional changes to get the server to work on the local network?

Comment: `guest account` is valid only in the `[global]` section, and is invalid in a share context (see `man smb.conf`). Also it is wrong to set password for guest account. If you want to create a share with password-protected access, create non-guest account and assign share to it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov It still doesn't get detected.

Comment: "Still" doesn't mean anything because we don't know what you changed. Please, show actual full `smb.conf` (strip comments and empty lines).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov It was a problem with the router, it works now. Also the only thing I changed was remove the guest account entry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out restarting my router fixed it. I have no idea why it worked, but I guess it has something to do with the LAN network.